# check if there is a key in dictionary and extract another key at the same level

Tags: python

I had a peculiar problem. I have data organized by json lines (I am only showing one line) in which we have one dictionary and one list of dictionaries and I want to find the "quantity" in d2 only if the key for "color" is the same.

```
d1 : {"color": "blue","quantity": 5}
d2 : [{"color": "black", "quantity": 8}, {"color": "blue", "quantity": 3}]
```

In this case I need to find "quantity": 3 which corresponds to color "blue" in d2 as d1 contains "blue".

I just wanted to see if there is a better way to do it other than what I am doing right now:

```
color = d2['color']
 for element in d2:
     if 'color' in element:
           if color == element['color']:
              print(element['count'])
```

So I have to iterate over each element one by one. Is there a way to do it just by searching for keys in d2 without iterating?

Comment: No, you can't access values in a list directly without iterating, if you don't know the specific list index. You can simplify that iteration though: `element = next(i['quantity'] for i in d2 if i['color'] == d1['color'])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to iterate so your solution is pretty much correct. I mean another option would be just doing a list comprehension. So like `element = next(elem['quantity'] for elem in d2 if elem['color'] == d1['color'])` but I would highly recommend your code instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
quantity = next(d["quantity"] for d in d2 if d["color"] == d1["color"])
```

Mind you, `next()` still performs an iteration.

Alternatively, one could convert `d2` in a dict with colors as keys (assuming they're unique):

```
d2 = {d["color"]: d for d in d2}
quantity = d2[d1["color"]]["quantity"]
```